# Person schema is not detecting into Rich Results Test?

Tags: json, schema, schema.org, google-schemas

I have used Person schema on my site as per schema.org standard but the rich result testing tool is not detecting the person schema. As the older Structure data testing tool detects the person schema.

Is the person schema is supported by Google or not?

Person schema schema.org:- https://schema.org/Person

Testing screenshot:- https://a.cl.ly/E0ur0e69

Answer (score 4):

The Rich Results Test only reports top level entities that generate Rich Results in Google. Person is not one of them. Person is a supported entity, but only used inside other entities, like an author of a review.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue with "Person" schema type while trying to test my markup in Google's Rich Results Test tool. After spending much time online to find out the issue, came across a very good article that gives the answer to this issue. Apparently, not all schema types are supported in Google's Rich Test Result tool.

The following is a list of [Supported rich result types](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7445569#zippy=%2Csupported-types) that the Google's tool currently supports as mentioned in their Seach Console Help Page.

1. AMP article
2. Article
3. Breadcrumb
4. Carousel
5. Course
6. Critic Review
7. Dataset
8. Employer rating
9. Estimated salary
10. Event
11. FAQ
12. Fact check
13. Guided recipe
14. How-to
15. Image License
16. Job posting
17. Job training
18. Local business
19. Logo
20. Movie
21. Product
22. Q&A page
23. Recipe
24. Review snippet
25. Sitelinks searchbox
26. Software app
27. Special Announcement
28. Video

As you can see, schema type "Person" is not in the supported list.

Thanks to this wonderful article [SEO for 2021: How to Use Google's New Testing Tool for Structured Data](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/seo-2021-structured-data) written by [Anne Fernandez](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/author/anne-fernandez) that has some additional tips.

Comment: Not anymore, right now there's `ProfilePage` rich result type too.